# Bash script Array behavior

Tags: arrays, bash, for-loop

I'm still learning bash and this has had me stumped for days now.  I've tried so many different things and read so much about arrays and expanding lists and splitting strings etc etc and I still cannot figure out what I am doing wrong here.  Probably something really dumb, but still, can someone please take a look at this?

You can see the output below the script, it seems to me like this should be pretty basic, but for some reason,  the `gzip -9` and `./b.txt` are not getting together.   The first line `gzip -1 ./a.txt` is fine,  but then the second line is broken, I just don't get it.

UPDATED SCRIPT so now there are no more warnings on shellcheck

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a toexec
toexec=("$(cat /root/devops/commands.txt)")
echo "toexec----"
printf '%s\n' "${toexec[@]}"
echo "-----"

declare -a dirlist
dirlist=("$(ls ./*)")

echo "dirlist----"
printf '%s\n' "${dirlist[@]}"
echo "-----"

declare -a toCompress
for (( i=0; i<${#dirlist[@]}; i++ ));
do
  toCompress[$i]="${toexec[$i]} ${dirlist[$i]}";
done
echo "toCompress----"
printf '%s\n' "${toCompress[@]}"
echo "-----"
```

**OUTPUT**

Output has changed since updating script, but still same issue..

```
toexec----
gzip -1
gzip -9
-----
dirlist----
./a.txt
./b.txt
-----
toCompress----
gzip -1
gzip -9 ./a.txt
./b.txt
-----
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
toexec----
gzip -1
gzip -9
-----
dirlist----
./a.txt
./b.txt
-----
toCompress----
gzip -1 ./a.txt
gzip -9 ./b.txt
-----
```

Here is a screenshot from shellcheck, i couldn't figure out how to link it
[image: shellcheck]

Comment: Your `dirlist` is a single element array. Try `dirlist=(*)`

Comment: Ok, thank you, I will.  On which line would I use that?  And question, why does the printf statement show two lines (a.txt and b.txt) for dirlist if its only one element?

Comment: Replace `dirlist=("$(ls ./*)")` with `dirlist=(*)`. Among other issues, the quotes around `"$(ls ./*)"` are ensuring that the contents of `dirlist` will be a single string containing all file names instead of a separate string (array entry) per file name. `toexec=("$(cat /root/devops/commands.txt)")` has  the same problem but a different solution (grep `readarray`)

Comment: You should include sample input in your question and make sure some of your file names to be stored in `dirlist` contain white spaces and globbing chars like `*` and `?` and both double `"` and single `'` quotes so you can test that your script will handle them robustly. Ideally 1 would also contain a newline. Also tell us the purpose of the script - is it to execute the `gzip` commands or just print them so some later shell invocation can execute them or something else.

Answer (score 0):

So the fix for this ended up being that the `toexec` array was only returning one element.   Using `readarray` instead of `toexec=(cat filename)` seemed to do the trick. (as pointed out by @EdMorton).

I added a `joinByChar` function, it didn't help but I kept it cuz it was neat.  Also, `dirlist=(*)` instead of `dirlist=(ls ./*)` made the filenames into `a.txt,b.txt` instead of `./a.txt,./b.txt` so while it didn't make a difference, it seemed cleaner so I kept it.

My final result from `joinByChar` had a newline in it, no clue why, but I added another line to strip newlines using the `//` ism  .. please tell me that's ok.  :)

```
#!/bin/bash
function joinByChar {
  local IFS="$1"
  shift
  echo "$*"
}
declare -a toexec
readarray toexec < /root/devops/commands.txt
declare -a dirlist=(*)
declare -a toCompress
for (( i=0; i<${#dirlist[@]}; i++ ));
do
  toCompress[$i]=$(joinByChar ' ' "${toexec[$i]}" "${dirlist[$i]}");
  toCompress[$i]=${toCompress[$i]//[$'\t\r\n']}
done
```

Comment: No. Absolutely do not use `command eval`. Look up the `readarray` man page to populate an array from the contents of a file.

Comment: @EdMorton really?  why?  what else can i use to make this work?

Comment: Google "eval is evil shell". Use readarray.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks again!  Got rid of command eval :)

Comment: @EdMorton So now I need to run those gzip commands,  if eval is evil, what shall i use ?

Comment: `sh` springs to mind. Try `printf 'seq 10\n' | sh`

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for the help.  I'm trying to do floating point division now and going crazy lol.  `ratio2=$(("$ratio1" / "$ratio" | bc -l));` just returns a 'floored' integer :(

Comment: figured it out ` ratio2=$(echo "scale=3; $ratio1 / $ratio" | bc -l);`